# How to delay print to pdf in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, charts, headless

I have a dashboard that contains multiple charts. The charts listen for parent DOM width changes and resize to it but it takes some time to do that.

When I press Cmd+P in Chrome it shrinks the viewport and reorganizes some DOM elements but it doesn't wait for the JS to rerender the charts.

Problem is Chrome doesn't wait for it, as a result, the charts are not getting rendered to full width.

You can go to https://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/dashboards/wealth-management-dashboard-with-export/ to check it out yourself.

Is there a way to tell Chrome to take the screenshot after the JS is done rerendering. Let's say I will get a callback when the charts are ready.

P.S. I am asking this to do a similar implementation in Chrome headless. So if it is not possible in Chrome maybe it is possible in Chrome headless. All answers are welcome.

Comment: Do you have control of the JS? It sounds like a solution would be better implemented there.

Comment: Yeah. I have control of the JS.

Comment: I would recommend posting your issue -- with your code -- over on Stack Overflow instead. Chrome doesn't have functionality to change this behavior.